# how to read another script from inside bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash script from inside my current one with the following command:

```
output=$(bash ./read.sh -f "$file" -c "$ARG1_COLUMN" -e "$ARG2_PATTERN")
```

read.sh is in the same dir as my current script and I've ensured that the flags and args are not null and have the values necessary.

when I try to echo "$output", I get a blank line

any ideas?

Comment: Well, what does `./read.sh` contain? What does `bash ./read.sh -f "$file" -c "$ARG1_COLUMN" -e "$ARG2_PATTERN"` print?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in the same directory as the current script. Pathnames are interpreted relative to the user's working directory, not the directory of the script.

Comment: So try using the absolute pathname of `read.sh` instead of `./`